# scrollify - scroll normally after last section?

Tags: jquery-scrollify

Is it possible with the scrollify plugin to scroll normally after last section? For example I have 6 sections and then a footer, I want scrolling after the last section to be normal. Right now, because footer isn't a section, I can't even scroll to it.

Answer (score 4):

I disable scrollify when viewport is below of last slide and enable it in otherwise:

```
$(document).on('scroll', function(e){
    var top = $('.slider .slide:last').offset().top;
    var screenTop = $(document).scrollTop();

    if (top > screenTop && $.scrollify.isDisabled()) {
            $.scrollify.enable();
            $.scrollify.update();
    } else if (top < screenTop && !$.scrollify.isDisabled()) {
            $.scrollify.disable();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try making the footer and interstitialSection. 
That way Scrollify will still scroll to it but won't manipulate its height.